# How to display details of an item next to the parent in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have multiple datasets listed on a page and I would like on clicking on some of them to display its details just below it.
I also would like to change the routing on click, for example from '/datasets' to '/datasets/1234567'.

I added the routing to '/datasets', but I can't figure out how to tell Angular 2 to display the item details next to the summary. I tried to add one router-outlet element next to each summary with the idea to display the details in this element, but I can't specify the "name" attribute of the router-outlet to be the Id of the dataset for example {{dataset.id}} - the template parser throws syntax error.

Please check the attached screencast.[image]

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed. A Plunker would be quite helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I overestimated the challenge. There are a few ways to achieve it:

1. The parent component - those which prints the datasets will create a `router-outlet` element. Then, a child route `:id` will be added and dataset details will be rendered in the `router-outlet` element. The router-outlet element then can be displayed next to dataset summary using CSS.
2. The child component (dataset-details) may notify the parent which is the `id` of the dataset. Then, the parent component will render a `render-outlet` next to the summary of the dataset with the same id.